# Java - Json deserialize data []

Tags: java, json, gson

I am new to stackoverflow.

I am creating an Java application which it will get data from a web server. The data is in json format. Example"

```
[
  {
    "item_name": "Adame",
    "item_type": "Special",
    "item": "Chestplate",
    "item_min_lvl": "50",
    "enchantment": {
      "health": "0.3",
      "dam": "24%",
      "life": "0.1",
      "xp": "24%",
      "loot": "22%"
    },
    "def": "73"
  },
  {
    "item_name": "Sticks'",
    "item_type": "Unique",
    "item": "Stick",
    "item_min_lvl": "4",
    "enchantment": {
      "health": "0.6",
      "mana": "1",
      "dam": "12%",
      "life": "0.3",
      "xp": "17%",
      "loot": "17%"
    },
    "min_dam": "39",
    "max_dam": "34"
  }
]
```

I know how to deserialize json using Gson. As you can see, it's started with `[`. I never deserialize this case before. Also, the json data is not the same(e.g. `enchantment`). I also searched in Google but I can't find any similar case. Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: The enclosing `[` and `]` just mean that the data is an array of objects.

Comment: @geoand Yea i know. But how can I deserialize it? Usually it will like this `Data[] data;` but there is no `data` before `[`

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Sometimes the outer layer of a JSON string is an object (Map) sometimes an array (List).  It simply depends on the data being described.

Comment: And if you don't know what a Map or a List is, study up on those before you try to tackle JSON.

Comment: @HotLicks I said I know JSON. Actually I just don't know how to deserialize it...

Comment: To deserialize it you use a deserializer.  There are about two dozen kits to choose from for Java (some listed on json.org).  The problem is that the Java folks in particular are really into these complex ones (eg, Jackson) that spit out custom Java objects, rather than simple Maps and Lists, and those are hard to understand and hard to get working right.  With JSON simple is good.

Comment: @HotLicks I know.. I said I know. I just don't how to to deserialize THIS type of json

Comment: You deserialize it the way you'd deserialize any JSON.  Only instead of getting a Map out you get a List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code. You will get the answer of your question. It's an List with 2 items.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("resources/json1.txt")));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
}
reader.close();

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyJSON>>() {
}.getType();
List<MyJSON> list = gson.fromJson(builder.toString(), listType);
// you can try this form as well
// MyJSON[] list = gson.fromJson(builder.toString(), MyJSON[].class);

for (MyJSON json : list) {
    System.out.println(json.toString());
}

...

class MyJSON {
    String item_name;
    String item_type;
    String item;
    String item_min_lvl;
    Enchantment enchantment;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append("\nitem_name:").append(item_name);
        builder.append("\nitem_type:").append(item_type);
        builder.append("\nitem:").append(item);
        builder.append("\nitem_min_lvl:").append(item_min_lvl);

        builder.append("\n\nEnchantment Details:");
        builder.append("\nhealth:").append(enchantment.health);
        builder.append("\ndam:").append(enchantment.dam);
        builder.append("\nlife:").append(enchantment.life);
        builder.append("\nxp:").append(enchantment.xp);
        builder.append("\nloot:").append(enchantment.loot);
        return builder.toString();
    }
}

class Enchantment {
    String health;
    String dam;
    String life;
    String xp;
    String loot;
}
```

output:

```
item_name:Adame
item_type:Special
item:Chestplate
item_min_lvl:50

Enchantment Details:
health:0.3
dam:24%
life:0.1
xp:24%
loot:22%


item_name:Sticks'
item_type:Unique
item:Stick
item_min_lvl:4

Enchantment Details:
health:0.6
dam:12%
life:0.3
xp:17%
loot:17%
```

---

**EDIT**

The structure of each entry is not same hence you can't use POJO for this type of JSON.

Simply use `ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>` and access the value based on key from the map.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>>() {
}.getType();
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = gson.fromJson(builder.toString(), listType);

for (Map<String, Object> json : list) {
    for (String key : json.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + ":" + json.get(key));
    }
    System.out.println("===========");
}
```

output:

```
item_name:Adame
item_type:Special
item:Chestplate
item_min_lvl:50
enchantment:{health=0.3, dam=24%, life=0.1, xp=24%, loot=22%}
def:73
===========
item_name:Sticks'
item_type:Unique
item:Stick
item_min_lvl:4
enchantment:{health=0.6, mana=1, dam=12%, life=0.3, xp=17%, loot=17%}
min_dam:39
max_dam:34
===========
```

Comment: nop. `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` i got this

Comment: @user3646662 I think now you can proceed.

Comment: @user3646662 Here is the complete updated in post. Its array not map.

Comment: @user3646662 If still you are getting Map then modify my program accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! <3 I will try it soon. Btw you forgot to put `mana`, `def` and `"min_dam` and `max_dam`

Comment: @user3646662 Should I do it perfectly 100% complete code for you. Now you have an idea. just add/remove as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi, I got this error. `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2`

Comment: I fixed it. Now is `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 5030`. I use json validator to valid it. It said it is a valid json

Comment: Column 5030 is an empty array. It doesn't have `enchantment`.
Others item: `enchantment: { "whatever": "whatever"}` but this item is `enchantment: []`

Comment: All the entries must be in the same structure otherwise it will not work. Let me provide some other alternative.

Comment: Thanks your method work! But, it is just like remove `"` from the json?

Comment: Can you tell me what do you want? Now you have a List of Map. Simply iterate and access by key. I am working on your another question.

Comment: I know. But since I need to loop it, does it cause high performance? There will be 100+ of items

Comment: No there will not any issue for just 100 items. It will hamper the performance if they are in millions or more. Just try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually valid in Java and with GSON:

```
YourObject[] locs = gson.fromJson (someJsonString, YourObject[].class);
```

It'll parse and return an array of `YourObject`. Just create Java Classes that represent your JSON objects, and replace the placeholders as necessary.

EDIT:
As Braj said before, you can create a fully formed POJO, including the other, (non-symmetrical) attributes (I'm borrowing the code from from Braj's answer here):

```
//... snip ...
class MyJSON
{
    String      item_name;
    String      item_type;
    String      item;
    String      item_min_lvl;
    Enchantment enchantment;

    // Heres the other attributes
    String      min_dam;
    String      max_dam;
}
//... snip ...
```

GSON will parse it and set the values to `null` if they aren't provided in the original JSON.

However, from the other question, it seems that the JSON ([Java - JSON Parser Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718739/java-json-parser-error)) for enchantment is provided inconsistently, so this will cause issues. I would recommend sending JSON for enchantment as an array for consistency, then you could structure your POJO as:

```
 //... snip ...
class MyJSON
{
    String      item_name;
    String      item_type;
    String      item;
    String      item_min_lvl;
    Enchantment[]   enchantment;

    // Heres the other attributes
    String      min_dam;
    String      max_dam;
}
//... snip ...
```

Comment: Please share the code. What will be the structure of `YourObject` here? Look at the JSON string again, it's not symmetric.

Comment: And for you information I have already shared this line in my post.

Comment: @Braj Sorry, didn't notice, had this question open for a while.

You can have a fully formed POJO with `min_dam` and `max_dam` as a `String` attributes. GSON will parse it and just set the values to `null` if they aren't set in the original JSON anyway. An example from your MyJSON above:
`class MyJSON
    {
        String item_name;
        String item_type;
        String item;
        String item_min_lvl;
        Enchantment enchantment;

        String min_dam;
        String max_dam;
    }`
You can make a distinction between the types by checking if those values are `null`

Comment: The values are dynamic. some time `"enchantment": {}`, `"enchantment": []` or not at all.

Comment: Yes you can add more information in your post to make it clear.

Comment: Look at other post of the OP [Java - JSON Parser Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718739/java-json-parser-error)

Comment: @Braj Just had a look at that now, it seems like the JSON from the OP is not structured consistently. If its structured properly, i.e, the "enchantment" is always provided as a JSON array (single, multiple, non-existent values or otherwise), you can just have it as an Enchantment[] in the POJO.

I'll update my post, was busy with something else. Sorry about that.

Comment: Have you tried with all the possibilities of `enchantment` as mentioned in my above comments?

Comment: @Braj it crashes with an `IllegalStateException`. Again, its not "well/consistently" formed JSON