# Java - JSON Parser Error

Tags: java, json, gson

I am creating an application which it will send `http` request to a web server. The return will be in `json`. Here is how the `json` look like

```
[//I used a tool to make it beautiful and easy to read.
  {
    "item_name": "Adame",
    "item_type": "Special",
    "item": "Chestplate",
    "item_min_lvl": "50",
    "enchantment": {
      "health": "0.3",
      "dam": "24%",
      "life": "0.1",
      "xp": "24%",
      "loot": "22%"
    },
    "def": "73"
  },
  {
    "item_name": "Sticks'",
    "item_type": "Unique",
    "item": "Stick",
    "item_min_lvl": "4",
    "enchantment": {
      "health": "0.6",
      "mana": "1",
      "dam": "12%",
      "life": "0.3",
      "xp": "17%",
      "loot": "17%"
    },
    "min_dam": "39",
    "max_dam": "34"
  },
  {
    "item_name": "Sword'",
    "item_type": "Unique",
    "item": "Sword",
    "item_min_lvl": "8",
    "enchantment": [], //colonm 30 is [
    "min_dam": "9",
    "max_dam": "10"
  }
]
```

Are you can see, the data inside the array are different. I got this error, `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 30`. This is my code:

```
MyJSON[] data = gson.from(jsonString, MyJSON[].class);

class MyJSON {
    String item_name;
    String item_type;
    String item;
    String item_min_lvl;
    Enchantment enchantment;
    String min_dam;
    String max_dam;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append("\nitem_name:").append(item_name);
        builder.append("\nitem_type:").append(item_type);
        builder.append("\nitem:").append(item);
        builder.append("\nitem_min_lvl:").append(item_min_lvl);

        builder.append("\n\nEnchantment Details:");
        builder.append("\nhealth:").append(enchantment.health);
        builder.append("\ndam:").append(enchantment.dam);
        builder.append("\nlife:").append(enchantment.life);
        builder.append("\nxp:").append(enchantment.xp);
        builder.append("\nloot:").append(enchantment.loot);
        return builder.toString();
    }
}

class Enchantment {
    String health;
    String dam;
    String life;
    String xp;
    String loot;
    String mana;
}
```

Can anyone help me to improve my code so my code an parse the `json` in different case. Thanks in advanced. (P.s. that's not my web server so I can't do anything with the json)

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **Valid JSON** unless you have added comments just to show lines where is the issue?

Comments should not be part of JSON.

Here is the code that I have already shared you at you another post [Java - Json deserialize data []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710037/java-json-deserialize-data?answertab=votes#tab-top).

You have to use `ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>` because the entries in the JSON string are not symmetric. You can't convert it into POJO in this case.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("resources/json2.txt")));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
}
reader.close();

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>>() {
}.getType();
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = gson.fromJson(builder.toString(), listType);

for (Map<String, Object> json : list) {
    for (String key : json.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + ":" + json.get(key));
    }
    System.out.println("===========");
}
```

output:

```
item_name:Adame
item_type:Special
item:Chestplate
item_min_lvl:50
enchantment:{health=0.3, dam=24%, life=0.1, xp=24%, loot=22%}
def:73
===========
item_name:Sticks'
item_type:Unique
item:Stick
item_min_lvl:4
enchantment:{health=0.6, mana=1, dam=12%, life=0.3, xp=17%, loot=17%}
min_dam:39
max_dam:34
===========
item_name:Sword'
item_type:Unique
item:Sword
item_min_lvl:8
enchantment:[]
min_dam:9
max_dam:10
===========
```

---

**EDIT**

enchantment return something like

```
enchantment:{health=0.6, mana=1, dam=12%, life=0.3, xp=17%, loot=17%}.
```

How can I get for example health?

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {
}.getType();
String string = "{health=0.6, mana=1, dam=12%, life=0.3, xp=17%, loot=17%}";
Map<String, String> map = new Gson().fromJson(string, mapType);
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + ":" + map.get(key));
}
```

output:

```
health:0.6
mana:1
dam:12%
life:0.3
xp:17%
loot:17%
```

Comment: This will work in all the case whatever is the JSON string. whether it contains `enchantment:[]` or `enchantment:{}` or not at all.

Comment: `enchantment` return something like `enchantment:{health=0.6, mana=1, dam=12%, life=0.3, xp=17%, loot=17%}`. How can I get for example `health`? Sorry I am stupid

Comment: Treat it as JSON string and again convert it into appropriate object type .Should I code for you?

Comment: I have added it my post as well. just remove `enchantment:` then then parse rest JSON string into Map

Comment: Check out my latest question please :3

Answer (score 2):

Basically this line of JSON

```
"enchantment": [], //colonm 30 is [
```

doesn't match your POJO. You're expecting an `Enchantment` object, but the JSON is giving you an array. Fix your JSON to return an empty JSON object or nothing at all for the `enchantment` pair.

```
"enchantment": {}
```

Comment: How do I fix? I said this is not my web server.

Comment: @Jeremy Well, you can't map the JSON to different POJOs. Your only other option is to not map it to a POJO and either use `JsonNode` or a `LinkedHashMap` as the Java representation.

Comment: @Jeremy In your gson `fromJson(..)`, try using `JsonElement` (or `JsonObject`). I don't have a computer where I can test it right now.

Comment: Can you write me some example code please? I really I no idea about `JsonElement` or `JsonObject`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom list type in Gson's fromJson() method to map it to a list of POJOs

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Enhancement>>() {}.getType();
List<Enhancement> enhancements = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, listType);
```

You will get a `List<Enhancement>`.

Comment: You can cast it to List<Enhancement> or directly collect it to List<Enhancement>! It will work